# Android C2DM-Error

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Registration from device (android phone running 2.2) is not working.

In one emulator im getting the registration id and if i try with another emulator(Google API version:8,same as the first).Im getting this warning. How to handle it.

LogCat shows the following warning -

```
07-27 11:54:23.621: WARN/ActivityManager(73): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) }: not found
```

I used the [vogella](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) site for the implementation of the C2DM. Its sometimes works n sometimes doesn't. **Why?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inorder to c2dm to work: 
1.Device must be running Android 2.2  or higher. 
2.Market application has to be installed on the device(necessary for a real device but not necessary for the emulator.)  
3.Users must be signed in with his google account.(settings\accounts...).
You should check out the [C2DM Framework web site](http://code.google.com/intl/tr/android/c2dm/) it explains the necessities.

> --It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the
>   Market application installed. However, you are not limited to
>   deploying your applications through Market. 
>   
> --It uses an existing
>   connection for Google services. This requires users to set up their
>   Google account on their mobile devices.

Here is a sample code:

```
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender",test@gmail.com);
    ComponentName name = applicationContext.startService(registrationIntent);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to need a market application to be installed for working with C2DM?

Comment: @Hussain: yes it is necessary if you are working on a real device but on the emulator its not necessary.

Comment: But i can get the registration id in the htc wildfire,but i cant get in emulator sometimes.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall(when you are using emulator?)that might be the reason i dont know which ports c2dm uses but i have never successfully have worked it in emulator in work(where i am behind a firewall) but at home everthing works like a charm.

Comment: Ya im behind the firewall, but if the firewall is the case then registration should not occur. But in my case its working sometimes and giving error sometimes.

Comment: c2dm uses several connections that means several ports. in my case registiration was always sucsessfull but i wast get the messages. my suggestion is try this somewhere which does not firewall with emulator also make sure to use google api8 and there is at least one registered google account on the emulator. i am pretty sure in that case you will at least get an Registiration error always.(I have added my sample registiration code check that out.)

Comment: Ok. I will try, Thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: one thing i had to do also after loging the google account, is to restart the emulater

Answer (score 3):

make sure:

1. > you are using a Google device
2. > you have a Google user registered on the device.